# Adding configuration file in Rider IDE

Tags: c#, rider

I know the Rider IDE is fairly new but i actually like it :)

My question is however if anyone knows how to add a configuration file to your project (within rider)

All I can see is this:

[image]

Which as you can see doesn't seem to have a way for me to create an `Application Configuration file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Solution Explorer, right-click the project name and click New, and then click **File**. In the Name text box, enter a name .config (change a file extension)  and click OK. The new config file is added to your project.

Comment: Note that this doesn't do what it did in Visual Studio. Visual Studio will add a fairly complete app.config file but this creates a blank file.